# 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'classes_'

Tags: python, image-processing

I have several samples of images and I would like to predict if those images contain text/characters.

I get an error when I try running my code at this step :

```
model = cPickle.load(f)
is_text = model.predict(image_samples)
```

image_samples are my samples and model looks like this :

```
Pipeline(steps=[
    ('hog', HOGFeatures(cells_per_block=(2, 2), orientations=10,
                        pixels_per_cell=(5, 5), size=(20, 20))),
    ('clf', LinearSVC(C=2.0, class_weight=None, dual=True,
                      fit_intercept=True,
                      intercept_scaling=1, loss='l2', max_iter=None,
                      multi_class='ovr', penalty='l2',
                      random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0))
])
```

The error message I get is :

```
File "/home/parallels/Desktop/Python/ImageTextRecognition-master/userimageski.py", line 104, in select_text_among_candidates
is_text = model.predict(self.candidates['flattened'])

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py", line 37, in <lambda>
out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 180, in predict
return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 228, in predict
return self.classes_[indices]
AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'classes_'
```

Could anyone help me ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem . It is actually an issue with sklearn versions. run python2.7 in the terminal and check `>>> import sklearn` `>>> sklearn.__version__` if you have a very previous version than current and as of now 0.17.1 is current then you need to upgrade sklearn . Just do `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn` to upgrade and re run the code